# MultiScaleTileSource local image

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to set the local image for the MultiScaleTileSource?

```
protected override void GetTileLayers(int tileLevel, int tilePositionX, int tilePositionY, IList<object> tileImageLayerSources)
{
   var veUri = new Uri("Resources/image1.png", UriKind.Relative);
   tileImageLayerSources.Add(veUri); // Don't not work for me
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiScaleImage does not support local images.